# Up to date alternative to ObjectiveResource for iPhone+Rails?

Tags: iphone, ruby-on-rails, objectiveresource

I'm creating a Rails app with an iOS client and found [ObjectiveResource](http://iphoneonrails.com/). It looks awesome for CRUD operations, but it hasn't been updated since 2009 so it seems built for rails2 and the first iphone sdk. Does anyone know of a similar but up to date framework?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everybody's talking about [Restkit](http://restkit.org/) these days. I haven't tried it yet myself, though.

Answer (score 1):

You could have a look here: https://rhomobile.com/

It enables you to code mobile apps with a framework made in ruby and very close to Rails. Apps are compatible with most smartphones.

Comment: have you used it? is it buggy? i don't understand their pricing.

Answer (score 0):

Anybody ever used ASIHTTPRequest?
Ill be experimenting with it next view hours.

http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/

Comment: I noticed, we went for RestKit.